# create folder from server on another machine

Tags: php, wamp

1) i have a server hosting web page ( intranet ) . Intent is to create folders on another machine. How is it possible. (using php).

2 ) As of now what i understand is only if the two machine's have wamp installed on each, then it is possible ( only in www folder ). I need the folder's created outside of www. Is it possible to do symbolic link such that, creating in www folder will create in the symbolically linked folder. ?

3) any other alternative

Brgds,

kNish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just one specific other machine, I would simply mount the machine where you want to create folders on the server. That way you can access the folders on the other machine as if they were normal folders on the server.

I don´t know how to exactly do that in Windows / WAMP; I use Linux myself, so you´ll have to look around for details.

Answer (score 0):

Possible if you run a backend on both servers. Server A "sends a command" to Server B which parsing then "running it".

Comment: so u r saying that given backend on both servers, it is possible to do symbolic link from one folder to other such that creating a folder in one will create a folder in the other...?

Comment: Everything is possible that can be written in a program. Maybe it's my oversight but you (of course) cannot create a symlink on Server A that points to a folder on Server B but you can mimick symlinks attributes with special softwares/proxies/etc.